# Response "',' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $. in Asp.Net Core API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing API in Asp.Net Core 3.1, I have a POST method below (content type is `application/JSON`), I am passing an invalid JSON to the response deliberately and response is also very clear. But here my question is can I make changes to return the response like

> countryId is a required field

for this particular case. Please let me know if it can be done, otherwise, I am fine with this response also(because this response is also valid firs to check the content type is a valid JSON or not).

**Method:**

```
public ActionResult ValidateFields(ValidateFieldsRequest validateFieldsRequest)
        {
```

**Request class:**

```
public class ValidateFieldsRequest
{
    //string currencyCode, int countryId, string fieldName, string fieldValue

    [Required]
    public string currencyCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[1-9]\\d*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid fieldName.")]
    public int countryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "At least one field required")]
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }

}
```

**Request:**

```
{
    "currencyCode": "RUB",
    "countryId": ,
    "fields": [{
            "fieldName": "BIC or Bank Code",
            "fieldValue": "12345678901234567"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "Beneficiary Account Number",
            "fieldValue": "123456"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|6a64d7ad-495850db788356cd.",
    "errors": {
        "$.countryId": [
            "',' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $.countryId | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 28."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[RegularExpression("^[1-9]\\d*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid fieldName.")]
public int countryId { get; set; }
```

the error message is set above,  but actually the json you are sending can not be sent like this, you should set

```
"countryId": null ,
```

Comment: I am talking about the case, what if I am getting request like `"countryId": ,`

Comment: actually i have never saw a request from front developer without setting value of a specified field,  other wise he will remove the whole field. 
 try removing the field from your json

Comment: Let's suppose you don't have any control on the request and client is sending you this data

Comment: dear you cannot leave the "countryId"  empty ,  you have to set a value to it

Comment: but you have no control on client who is sending you the request, they can definitely send this request.

Comment: please read the "Unset property " part  in here :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8JB4/com.ibm.wbpm.wid.integ.doc/topics/rjsonnullunsempprops.html

Comment: So according to this it should give countryid is required message

Comment: "then the property will not appear in the JSON data."   according to this,  you should remove the "countryId" or set it to null

Comment: Dear it's the client who's sending request and I don't have any control on the request data

Comment: then please contact your client, and discuss with him about it

Comment: @viveknuna I'm encountering your issue right now. We don't have control on what the client is sending. Debugging becomes hard with a misleading response like "is an invalid start of a property". The client thought that the issue is in our system instead of theirs.

Answer (score 0):

the json of the request is not correct: you have to pass something as country id:

```
{
    "currencyCode": "RUB",
    "countryId": "",
    "fields": [{
            "fieldName": "BIC or Bank Code",
            "fieldValue": "12345678901234567"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "Beneficiary Account Number",
            "fieldValue": "123456"
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "currencyCode": "RUB",
    "countryId": null,
    "fields": [{
            "fieldName": "BIC or Bank Code",
            "fieldValue": "12345678901234567"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "Beneficiary Account Number",
            "fieldValue": "123456"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Let's suppose you don't have any control on the request and client is sending you this data

Comment: then the client won't get any response but that error because the json is not properly correct.
The client should at least send a json with a correct syntax.